# Replace a string at the beginning and end only

Tags: string, go

I want to replace first `a` and last `a` but not the `a` in the `abcd`.

Currently, it returns `hello hellobcd hello` but I would like to have `hello abcd hello`

The reason I use `ReplaceAll` is that I don't necessarily know the position and amount of how `a` appears. But if `a` in a combined string, I don't want to replace it, but just leave it as it is. What will be a solution in Go to solve this problem?

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    item := "hello"
    test := "a abcd a"
    s := "a"

    item = strings.ReplaceAll(test, s, item)
    fmt.Println(item)
}
```

Output:

```
hello hellobcd hello
```

Playground:
https://play.golang.org/p/D1VzvipblKu

Comment: Do you want to replace the first and the last `a` because it's at the beginning and end of the string, or because it's not part of a larger word?

Comment: Use ` a ` (surrounded by a space on either side) as test and handle edge cases individually (when strings starts and/or ends with `a`).

Comment: Not because in the first and last place, just because it is not part of large word

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a regular expression:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "regexp"
)

func main() {
    regexForA := regexp.MustCompile(`\ba\b`)
        test := "a abcd a"
        output := regexForA.ReplaceAllLiteralString(test,`hello`)
        fmt.Println(output)
}
```

Output:

```
hello abcd hello
```

Playground link to run this example: https://play.golang.org/p/Cs99TrQDUtK

Comment: I read this quote today and it made me question my answer to this: “some people, when confronted with a problem, think ‘I know, I’ll use regular expressions.’ Now they have two problems”

Answer (score 0):

You can split the problem into two: first take the string from the start and do a plain replace with a limit of one. That will give you:

> hello abcd a

Then you reverse the string and do the same thing. You can for sure do it a lot more optimized, but that will get the job done and is still quite readable:

```
func Reverse(s string) (result string) {
  for _,v := range s {
    result = string(v) + result
  }
  return 
}

func main() {
    item := "hello"
    test := "a abcd a"
    s := "a"

    result := strings.Replace(test, s, item, 1)
    result = Reverse(strings.Replace(Reverse(result), s, Reverse(item), 1))

    fmt.Println(result)
}
```

prints

> hello abcd hello

Note you need to reverse the first input string, your replacement and then the result to get it back into the right order.

playground link: https://play.golang.org/p/tuzxehhnEDu

Answer (score -1):

If I were doing such thing, I'd just split string (strings.Fields) and then replace basing on string comparison, pseudocode:

```
for i, field := range fields {
    if field == "a" {
        fields[i] = "hello"
    }
}
```

I wrote it on phone and never tested, but You should understand a concept :)